# Can not find LucenePDFDocument class in pdfbox-2.0.2.jar

Tags: lucene, pdfbox

I want to parse pdf document to be indexed by Lucene using pdfbox package. The required class LucenePDFDocument which is in org.apache.pdfbox.examples.lucene.LucenePDFDocument package. But in the jar file I have not found it. So, my java program is not getting compiled.

Kindly help!!!

Comment: It isn't in the pdfbox*.jar. Examples are in the source code download, https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi or in the repository: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/lucene/

Comment: So will I need to compile it from source?

Comment: Yes, indeed. See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1356

Comment: Does this solve your problem? If yes, please answer the question yourself or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of the question goes as follows...

1. Previously before pdfbox version 1.7.1, org.apache.pdfbox.examples package was included but there is no package as examples.lucene.LucenePDFDocument.
2. From 1.7.1 there is no org.apache.pdfbox.examples package.
3. So, in order to use LucenePDFDocument class in your application, one has to compile the source and make a jar and use it in the application. In the source there is a example package directory. So, example package will be included once compiled from source.